# Limit access to Kubernetes secret by RBAC

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I have set up Kubernetes secrets.

```
kubectl create secret generic mysecret --from-file=mysecret=/home/ubuntu/secret.txt
```

And this secret can be converted to plaintext using the same `kubectl` command:

```
kubectl get secret mysecret -o yaml
# and base64 decode
```

How do I limit access to this secret? I only want a certain pods and only me as an operator to have access to this secret.

Comment: When you say limit access, do you mean read, write?

Comment: Yes, I want to limit read and write access.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, so you need to define a (cluster) role and then bind it to you (== human user is the target entity) and/or to a service account (== app is the target entity) which you then [use in the pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) instead of the `default` one.

The respective `secretadmin` role (or choose whatever name you prefer) would look something like this (vary verbs as required):

```
$ kubectl create clusterrole secretadmin \
          --verb=get --verb=list --verb=create --verb=update  \
          --resource=secret \
          --namespace=mysuperproject
```

Once you've defined the role, you can attach (or: bind) it to a certain entity. Let's go through the case of the service account (similar then for a human user, just simpler). So first we need to create the service account, here called `thepowerfulapp` which you will then use in your deployment/pod/whatever:

```
$ kubectl -n mysuperproject create sa thepowerfulapp
```

And now it's time to tie everything together with the following binding called `canadminsecret`

```
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding canadminsecret \
          --role=secretadmin \
          --serviceaccount=mysuperproject:thepowerfulapp \
          --namespace=mysuperproject
```

Comment: Isn't it true that also any user able to create a Pod in the `mysuperproject` namespace will be able to mount the Secret in a container and see it?

Comment: Yes @giorgiosironi this is a known limitation of RBAC in Kubernetes, IOW it would be desirable if it would be more fine-grained, being able to address individual resources rather than on the namespace/kind level. See also this excellent KubeCon talk by Vallery Lancey & Seth McCombs where they discuss said issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZ73EBP2a9Q

Comment: the `--namespace` flag is unnecessary since you are creating clusterrole/clusterrolebindings, these resources are not bound to a namespace, they create cluster wide access controls.